# Vue-router beforeRouteEnter Vue-Resource request

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router, vue-resource

I have used this link as a reference to make a request before entering a route:
https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/data-fetching.html

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
Vue.use(VueResource)

function getCities () {
    return Vue.http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: process.env.base_url + 'cities'
  })
}

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      cities: []
    }
  },

  beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
    getCities((err, cities) => {
      if (err) {
        next(false)
      } else {
        next(vm => {
          vm.cities = cities.data
        })
      }
    }) 
   },
   
   watch: {
     $route () {
       this.cities = []

       getCities((err, cities) => {
         if (err) {
           this.error = err.toString()
         } else {
           this.cities = cities.data
         }
       })
     }
   }
```

However it doesn't seem to be working for me. I have tested this code and the request is successfully being made. However the result is not being returned. Currently, the request itself is being returned from the function, but I cannot show it in the beforeRouteEnter callback where it supposedly should assign it to vm.cities neither in the watch $route section.

Any help/opinion is appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I think I'm running into a similar issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, not yet. Everybody keeps referencing me the documentation, however can't seem to find the solution. Haven't tried a lot lately, but will do again soon. Will keep you posted @tjeezy

Comment: What versions of vue and vue-router are you using? Also, did you put console.log statements throughout? You sure `err` is falsy?

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't go there at all. neither err, nor cities is being shown. I've put console.logs and it doesn't go neither in watch, nor in beforeRouteEnter

Comment: Can you show how your routing is set up or your mounted Vue app instance?

Answer (score 0):

The `Vue.http` method returns a promise, so the code should read:

```
beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
  getCities().then(response => {
    next(vm => vm.cities = response.body)
  }
}
```